# Calculate difference betweenrows based on another column_Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to compute difference between rows based on some column by using python/pandas. I guess I can explain better by using small examples. So, I have the following data:

```
 Number of rows       A             B
 1                    4             NaN
 2                    2             NaN
 3                    2             1
 4                    3             NaN
 5                    2             NaN
```

And I want to get following data:

```
 Number of rows      A            B           C
 3                   2            1           2
```

So, lets me explain what I did here. Firstly, I need to identify the rows of Column B, which has a value of 1 (As you can row Number 3 has a value 1). Then, I need to find the difference between 2 rows prior to and following to this row (row Number 3) and show the result as a column C. In our example 2 rows prior to row Number 3 is row Number 1 and 2 rows following the row Number 3 is row Number 5. And the difference between the values of row Number 1 and row Number 5 of COLUMN A is 2 (4-2 = 2)  (At the end, I will keep the rows only has value in Column C - this is an easy task and I do not need any help in that). 
I hope I can explain it. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to get the indexes and use `i-2` and `i+2`

```
i = df.loc[df.B.eq(1)].index.tolist()
j = [(i_-2,i_+2) for i_ in i ]

df.loc[df.B.eq(1), 'C'] = [df.A.iloc[a] - df.A.iloc[b] for (a,b) in j]

n   A   B   C
0   1   4   NaN NaN
1   2   2   NaN NaN
2   3   2   1.0 2.0
3   4   3   NaN NaN
4   5   2   NaN NaN
```

Or course can just slice again in `b=1` to have your expected output

```
df[df.B.eq(1)]
    n   A   B   C
2   3   2   1.0 2.0
```

Comment: RafaelC, many thanks again for your solve. How can we modify this to use without condition.I mean assume that we do not have column B. Just need to find the  the difference between 2 rows prior to and following to the all rows. Thanks again.

Comment: @Khalid but how do you expect the output to be? Because this would yield a whole new row, if I understood correctly

Comment: The issue is, I do have more than 1000 rows. So, in that case I will have a column name C. and each row (lets sat row Number 31) in this column will be equal the difference between 2 rows prior to (row Number 29) and the following to this row (row Number 33).

Comment: @khalid But the difference between two rows yields a new row. For example, if you have `(2, 3, 10, 9)` in row 29 and `(1, 1, 8, 2)` in row 31, then the result would be `(1, 2, 2, 7)`. How would you fit `(1, 2, 2, 7)` into a cell in column C?

Comment: In each row I have just one value. For example, I have 12 in row 29 and 3 in row 33. Then, in row 31, the cell in Column C, will be 9. The only difference between this and the main question is, I do not have a condition now. I meant I do not have a column name B.

Comment: I will open new question for that